# I don't understand this error when I try to use operators on %s on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I started out programming a few days ago. I did some course on the internet and I was now looking to make a simple program to solve a rule of three (cross multiplication) 
it goes as follow :

```
    # Def variables

    print "a/b = c/d"
    print "Put in the values you know. Leave the one that you dont know with a '?' "
    a = raw_input ("A = ")
    b = raw_input ("B = ")
    c = raw_input ("C = ")
    d = raw_input ("D = ")

    # if statements

    if a == "?":
        "%s * %s / %s" % (c, b, d) = "a"
        print "a"

     # in work elif b == "?"
```

when I run it, it says "*** can't assign to operator, line 13"
it seems to be a syntax error, but I really don't get it. Thanks for your patience :) Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Look at what you're doing. You're doing `something % something_else = a_third_thing`. Does that seem like legal syntax?

Comment: The error message says it all. On line 13, you wrote `"%s * %s / %s" % (c, b, d) = "a"`, that `= "a"` is where you're trying to assign the expression to `a`

Comment: What do you think `"%s * %s / %s" % (c, b, d) = "a"` is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"%s * %s / %s" % (c, b, d) = "a"` is invalid syntax.  You can't have an operator like that on the left hand side of an assignment because you're trying to assign something to the result of an expression -- But that doesn't really make sense ...

did you mean:

```
a = "%s * %s / %s" % (c, b, d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
"%s * %s / %s" % (c, b, d) = "a"
```

is invalid because you're trying to assign a string "*a*" to another string. Everything inside quotation marks is a string. The operation `"%s * %s / %s" % (c, b, d)` creates a string where *%s* is substituted with the value of c, b, d, like for example:

```
print "%s * %s / %s" % (2, 3, 4)
OUTPUT: 2 * 3 / 4
```

But according to your code you're trying to calculate and print *a* and should therefore do:

```
a = c * b / d
print(a)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried this, but it made an error :                                                    a/b = c/d
Put in the values you know. Leave the one that you dont know with a '?' 
A = ?
B = 100
C = 45
D = 50

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/ruleofthree.py", line 13, in <module>
    a = c * b / d
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
>>>

Comment: Yes, your variables are strings and must be converted to floats. Best way is to do a = float(c) * float(b) / float(d)

Comment: The reason why we use floats is because you're dividing. In Python 2.x, dividing an integer with an integer gives you an integer. For example `3 / 4 = 0` whilst `3.0 / 4.0 = 0.75`

Comment: Works even better! Thank you so much :)

Comment: and thanks for the clarification about dividing integer/floats!